# Tennis player sit-down (or other form of) protest?

Tags: tennis

A few years ago, many Brazilian football teams [sat-down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bemxbSrUnk) right after the match started, in protest for extenuating scheduling conditions.

Has there ever a player protested in akin ways in a professional Tennis match? For example, by refusing to serve? Or maybe two players, by keeping the ball in game continuously?

If so, can the referee do something about it?

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, do you mean the referee (the official who is *off-court* and responsible for the overall running of a tournament), the chair umpire (who is on-court and oversees the running of an individual match) or somebody else?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I guess I'm referring to the chair umpire.

Comment: IMO the chair umpire will warn the players but ultimately the offical referee would step in. The governing body (like the ATP) have rules around code of conduct but if someone did this on court they would not be liked by many people